# Is it okay to say this: "Do you like to have...?"

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I was just wondering. Is it OK to say this sentence?

> Do you like to have coffee tonight when you get home?

Comment: I would say "Would you like to have..".

Comment: _Do you like_ introduces a timeless or habitual question. It is inconsistent with asking about a particular occasion.

Comment: "**Do you want** to have coffee tonight when you get home?" is fine, but not with "like".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence is grammatically incorrect. As the other two users have pointed out, "would you" is the best choice for the sentence as it signifies a conditional (asking what someone prefers). To start the sentence with "do you" is incorrect because it uses present tense, while the time parameter (tonight) points to an event that will occur in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Either "**Do you want to have coffee tonight...**" or "**Would you like to have coffee tonight...**" would be more natural.

Answer (score 3):

real Future + real Future =   first conditional

If I get home, I will drink coffee.

My suggestion

Will you drink coffee tonight when you get home?

Comment: @MystiSinha I don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

The sentence you wrote is a mix of two constructs, which I know non-native English speakers have trouble with.

- "Do you like to have coffee when you go home?" is the continuous present, meaning "When you usually go home most nights, do you then like to have coffee?" It's not an invitation.

If you mean an invitation on a one-off occurrence, such as tonight, you use the conditional:

- "Would you like to have coffee when you go home tonight?"